# Consulta com Left Join considerando registros mais recentes da tabela auxiliar

Tags: mysql, join

Possuo duas tabelas:

```
curriculo (cur_codigo,cur_nome)
lembrete_envios (lem_codigo,lem_curriculo,lem_data,lem_tipo)
```

- A tabela **curriculo** armazena o ID do candidato e o nome do candidato
- A tabela **lembrete_envios** armazena lembretes enviados aos currículos
- **lem_curriculo** é a chave estrangeira de **cur_codigo**
- Cada currículo pode conter um ou mais lembretes.
- Quando o currículo possui mais de um lembrete vinculado, a pesquisa deve considerar a data do lembrete mais recente.

Estou com dificuldades para montar uma pesquisa que retorne os currículos que satisfaçam a duas condições, conforme discriminado abaixo:

A consulta deve retornar os curriculos que não possuem lembretes enviados ou que
possuam lembretes enviados sendo que o mais recente seja 7 dias anterior ao dia atual.

TESTE:

```
 INSERT INTO curriculo (cur_codigo, cur_nome) VALUES
   ('1', 'A'),
   ('2', 'B'),
   ('3', 'C');

 INSERT INTO lembrete_envio (lem_codigo,lem_curriculo,lem_data,lem_tipo) VALUES
   ('1', '1', '2020-01-01', '1'),
   ('2', '1', '2020-01-05', '1'),
   ('3', '1', '2020-02-08', '1'),
   ('4', '3', '2020-01-19', '1');
```

Para este exemplo, vamos considerar a data atual como sendo (2020-02-10).

Neste caso, a consulta deveria retornar os curriculos: B e C, pois

- **B** (não possui lembretes vinculados)
- **C** (o lembrete vinculado foi enviado há mais de 7 dias da data atual (10 é menor que 18)

Obs: **A** não pode constar nos resultados, pois o seu lembrete mais recente   (2020-02-08) não é inferior a 7 dias a contar da data atual.

```
 SELECT curriculo.cur_nome, max(lembrete_envio.lem_data)
 FROM curriculo LEFT OUTER JOIN lembrete_envio
 ON (curriculo.cur_codigo = lembrete_envio.lem_curriculo)
 WHERE lembrete_envio.lem_data BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 
 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
 OR lembrete_envio.lem_data IS NULL
 GROUP BY curriculo.cur_codigo;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a320d/8

Comment: Me tire uma dúvida: como você faria se, por exemplo, o dia atual fosse 05?

Comment: Tinha feito assim apenas para expor aqui o problema, mas já atualizei o campo para o tipo date aqui na questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o campo `lem_data`é efetivamente do tipo `date` então tente:

```
SELECT curriculo.cur_nome, max(lembrete_envio.len_data)
FROM curriculo LEFT OUTER JOIN lembrete_envio ON (curriculo.cur_codigo = lembrete_envio.lem_curriculo)
WHERE lembrete_envio.lem_data BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
   OR lembrete_envio.lem_data IS NULL
GROUP BY curriculo.cur_codigo;
```